# Trouble with the terminal os vsCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Im new programming in Python, and I come from Matlab. The problem with the terminal need a bit of context, so will go on.

I have two types of terminal.
-The first one, when I execute all the code, it appears the path of the archive below. Thats alright, but then, I cant write sth manually on the terminal, appears to be an error

-The second one, which only appears ">>>" below. It occurs when I execute sth thag I have selected before with the mouse. Here I actually can write sth manually, but I cant execute all the code.

I Wonder if there is a way to solve this or just to change between those types of terminals. Its awful having to close and reopen the terminal each time it occurs.

I just expect a way to change between each type of terminals or just knowing how to do it correctly

Comment: `python3 -i <somefile>.py`

Comment: Right.  You have three choices.  (1) Fire up the interactive interpreter, with `python`.  (2) Run a standalone script, with `python xxx.py`.  (3) Run a script and then start the interactive interpreter, with `python -i xxx.py`.  Python is not Matlab.  You need to learn the tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a new terminal, it is an ordinary **powershell** terminal, where you can execute shell commands, including commands to execute python scripts, such as

```
python demo01.py
```

[image]

If you type `python` and press enter, this will open the python interactive terminal, where you can directly enter python code and press enter to run

[image]

You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> or `exit()` to exit.

[image]

[vscode teminals](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/basics)